# How to Automate MS teams using cypress

Tags: cypress

```
describe('Two Domain urls in different Test case', function () {
  it('navigates', () => {
    cy.visit('https://teams.microsoft.com')
  })
})
```

tried using the above code, still not redirecting to login screen

It should redirect to login screen

Comment: Hello, what error do you get? Can you please post a screenshot of the runner + the result?

Comment: no error , on running the script , getting blank screen white

Comment: And what does the runner show before and after when you hover on the command? Did you try with a wait()?